# How do display in app purchase currency symbol

Tags: flutter

I have the following code which is working fine but it returns as currency name and price. For example,
GBP instead of £.

I want it to display the currency symbol. How can I do this?

```
String? getPrice() {
    try {
      return _items[0].currency! + ' ' + _items[0].price!;
    } catch (e) {
      return '£ 5.00 ';
    }
  }
```

Comment: So it sounds like `_items[0].currency` is a string, with the value "GBP", correct?  One approach might be to create a [map](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_map.htm) that translates "GBP" to "£", "USD" to "$", etc.

Comment: Hi thank you so much, Yes youre correct. Im new, in flutter can you give me a sample code so I can work on it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use this one

```
    var mainPrice = double.parse(_items[0].price!);
    var mainCurrency = _items[0].currency!;
    var formatter = NumberFormat.currency(symbol: mainCurrency);
    var result =  formatter.format(mainPrice);
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion.  But much depends on exactly what string values the OP is saving in "_items[].currency".  NumberFormat class documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/NumberFormat-class.html